# How to push array into json object in Firebase set() function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage, jsobject

I want to push new item to my firebase database.

Json object should look like this:

```
var newItem = {
            'address': "Кабанбай батыр, 53",
            'cityId': 1,
            'courierName': "Максат",
            'dispatcherId': "somedispatcherId",
            'info': "привезти к 2ому подъезу в 11 ч вечера", 
            'isCompleted': 0,
            'isProceeded': 0, 
            'name': "Адиль Жалелов" ,
            'paymentMethod': "наличка" ,
            'phone': "87775634456" ,
            'price': 5000,
            'products': []
        }
```

And the problem is that i cant push array of objects(*$scope.orders*) to **newItem**

i tried to push this $scope.orders:

```
   $scope.addOrder = function(){
        var orderRef = 
        firebase.database().ref().child('Orders').child('Astana');
        var newOrderKey = orderRef.push().key;
        var newJson = {
            'address': "Кабанбай батыр, 53",
            'cityId': 1,
            'courierName': "Максат",
            'dispatcherId': "somedispatcherId",
            'info': "привезти к 2ому подъезу в 11 ч вечера", 
            'isCompleted': 0,
            'isProceeded': 0, 
            'name': "Адиль Жалелов" ,
            'paymentMethod': "наличка" ,
            'phone': "87775634456" ,
            'price': 5000,
            'products': []
        };
         newJson['products'].push( $scope.orders);
        /*for (var i =0; i < $scope.orders.length ; i++){
            newJson['products'].push( $scope.orders[0]);
        } */

        console.log($scope.orders,newJson)
        orderRef.child(newOrderKey).set(newJson); 
    }
```

But i got error : ***Reference.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($$hashKey) in property....***

if console.log($scope.orders) then get

[image: xcxx]

Anyone who can help?

thanks in advance!

Comment: The error you have isn't about the push method. It is about the set. Can you add the code where you have the orderRef and newOrderKey please ? It looks like newOrderKey is invalid

Comment: @GabrielDiez check out) I think everything is ok with orderRef and OrderKey, because when i set json object witout **products** property it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firebase, `Push` method generates a new child location using a unique key and returns its Reference. So you already have the child and the reference of your child. You don't need to add a child to your orderRef like you tried.

You can simply do that

```
var newOrderKey = orderRef.push();  // Return the ref of the futur child
newOrderKey.set(newJson);
```

Also there is an issue with object from angular, the '$' in '$$hashKey' is the issue. Angular creates the $$hashKey properties.

This should fix the issue

```
newJson['products'].push( angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.orders)));
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but it also gives an error: Reference.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($$hashKey) in property....

Comment: try this newJson['products'].push( angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.orders))); When you are trying to push order from the scope

Comment: Oh thanks man! `angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.orders))` did the trick